# Deploying React to GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

I followed these tutorials:

https://pages.github.com/

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Right now my repo name is: username.github.io [username replaced with mine].

I am confused on what I am supposed to put on my package.json file because it conflicts with the React deploy tutorial. This is what I have right now [username replaced with mine]:

```
{
    "name": "personal-website",
    "homepage": "https://username.github.io",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
      "react": "^15.6.1",
      "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
      "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
      "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "predeploy": "npm run build",
      "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
}
```

Every time I load to the username.github.io page, it only displays the README.md file and not the actual React application. My index.html file has to be in the public directory or else npm start will not load properly. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/shinnn/gulp-gh-pages. 
I use that lib myself to deploy a react application to github pages: https://github.com/madnight/githut/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js

Comment: I used gulp; I get the error below. It seems like theres no easy way to host React

$ gulp deploy
[22:17:21] Using gulpfile ~/personal-website/gulpfile.js
[22:17:21] Starting 'deploy'...
/usr/lib/nodejs/strip-bom/index.js:4
        throw new TypeError('Expected a string, got ' + typeof x);
TypeError: Expected a string, got object
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/nodejs/strip-bom/index.js:4:15)
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/vinyl-fs/lib/src/getContents/bufferFile.js:13:23
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)

Comment: I appreciate your help. I decided to use surge instead because it was 10x easier to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to add an extension to the URL after GitHub. So, I ended up using surge instead:
http://jakewiesler.com/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project/

It works and is very easy to use.

Comment: as an updated link: [post now available on medium blog](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089)